# Find all messages in a thread

Tags: email, applescript

For the given message, I want to get all messages in its thread, e.g.:

```
tell application "Mail"
    if content of theMessage contains "merged #" then
        # repeat with otherMessage in the thread of theMessage
            set background color of otherMessage to green
        # end repeat
    end if
end tell
```

How do I do that / is it possible at all?

(I know I can iterate over all messages in the mailbox of `theMessage` and compare subjects, but this isn't efficient)

Comment: Applescript Mail instructions do not support threads. the work around is to select all message for which title contains xxxx and then loop through that list.

Comment: @pbell, thanks. Seems like I should use `set theThreadMessages to messages of theMailbox whose subject is equal to subject of theMessage`. Do you know, is there a way to canonize subject (e.g. strip out all 'fwd:' and 're:' etc.)?

Comment: instead of "whose subject is equal to", you should use "whose subject contains". AS will give you all messages  for which part of subject is what you're looking for.

Comment: But string `'subject'` does not contain string `'re: subject'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you receive a message with subject `re: subj`, you won't be able to find a message with subject `fwd: subj` using `contains` operator.

So here is a function to strip `re` and `fwd`:

```
-- Email subject canonization
-- Strips 're:', 'fwd:', etc. from the beginning of the text string passed in.
on canonizeSubject(theSubject)
    return do shell script "export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8; export LANG=en_US.UTF-8; shopt -u xpg_echo; echo " & quoted form of theSubject & " | perl -C -Mutf8 -pe 's/^(re|fwd|\\s|:)*//i'"
end canonizeSubject
```

The usage is:

```
set theSubject to my canonizeSubject(subject of theMessage)
set messagesInTheThread to messages of mailbox of theMessage whose subject contains theSubject
```

But actually, it's not a complete fair way of grouping emails. To be correct, you should group into threads not by matching theirs subject, but by searching the original message using `References` header.

See details here: https://cr.yp.to/immhf/thread.html

Comment: You've made the subject a saint?

Answer (score 0):

that's the other way around : 're:subject' contains 'subject'.
here is a small script which reads mails with same part of subject :

```
set myTitle to "subject of my thread" --only the subject without 're:' or 'Fwd:'
tell application "Mail"
set myEmails to {}
set MailSent to {every message of sent mailbox whose subject contains myTitle}
set Mailreceived to {every message of inbox whose subject contains myTitle}
set BoxList to name of every mailbox
repeat with aBox in BoxList
    set end of myEmails to {every message of mailbox aBox whose subject contains myTitle}
end repeat
end tell
display dialog "sent=" & (count of MailSent) & return & "receipt=" & (count of Mailreceived) & return & "other=" & (count of myEmails)
```